# Necesito ayuda con un codigo de py basico

Tags: python-3.7

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
#Patalla de inicio
sg.theme('LightBrown6')
disenho=    [[sg.Text('Ingrese su nombre',font='Verdana 12')],
            [sg.InputText()],#valor de lista 0
            [sg.Text('Ingrese el tamaño del tablero',font='verdana 12')],
            [sg.InputText()],#valor de lista 1
            [sg.Button('Ok'),sg.Button('Cancel')]]

ventana=sg.Window('Hola usuario', disenho)

while True:
    event, values= ventana.read()
    #validacion
    while float(values[1])<3 or float(values[1])%2!=0 or float(values[1])>20:
        sg.popup('Introduce un valor valido',
            title='error')
        if event==sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=='OK':
            break

    if event==sg.WIN_CLOSED or event=='Cancel':
        break
    ventana.close()
```

Todos mis problemas estan en la seccion  de validacion con el while. Cuando sale el popup no me deja cerrarlo y  tengo errores al momento de la validacion, pero no se cuales son

Answer (score 0):

cuando se aprita ok o se cierra `sg.WIN_CLOSED` devuelve `None`. solo se cambia el `if` en la parte del `while` a continuación te dejo el código con la solución

```
import PySimpleGUI as sg
#Patalla de inicio
sg.theme('LightBrown6')
disenho=    [[sg.Text('Ingrese su nombre',font='Verdana 12')],
            [sg.InputText()],#valor de lista 0
            [sg.Text('Ingrese el tamaño del tablero',font='verdana 12')],
            [sg.InputText()],#valor de lista 1
            [sg.Button('Ok'),sg.Button('Cancel')]]

ventana=sg.Window('Hola usuario', disenho)

while True:
    event, values= ventana.read()
    #validacion
    while float(values[1])<3 or float(values[1])%2!=0 or float(values[1])>20:
        sg.popup('Introduce un valor valido',
            title='error')
        if sg.WIN_CLOSED == None or event=='OK':
            break

    if sg.WIN_CLOSED == None or event=='Cancel':
        break
    ventana.close()
```

cualquier otra duda no dudes en comentar esta publicación. si ya se soluciono tu duda por favor apriete el tick de mi respuesta para que figure como resuelta